# Prolog game programming board evaluation

Tags: optimization, prolog

I have created a game, (4 in a row), in prolog. My heuristic function requires me to know how many Player's and Opponent's chips are in each possible 4-row combination on the board. The method I am using is as follows (in psuedocodish):

I have 1 list of all possible fours of the board (ComboList) =of the form==> `[[A,B,C,D]|Rest]`.
I have 1 list of all the moves of the 1st player (List1)     =of the form==> `[[1],[7],[14]]`
And 1 for opponent's moves (List2).

Step 1: obtain the first combo from ComboList, 2:
Check all of List1 to see how many are in this combo, 3:
Check all of List2 to see how many are in this combo,
Move onto the next combo from ComboList and start over...

This PROCESS takes waay too much runtime for what is required.

Please can someone suggest something better and more efficient! Much thanks in advance!

Comment: Just a comment, wouldn't it be better to define the what it means to have `4 in a row` rather than have a list of all possible combos? This seems more in line with prolog itself in that you want to prove if there is `4 in a row` rather than match if there is `4 in a row`.

Comment: I agree, but I am not looking for a '4 in a row' at this step. This step is for the heuristic function to evaluate the current position - for that I need to know how many chips of each player are in each combo. Thanks though

Comment: Ok, kind of skipped ahead, now I'm curious.

Answer (score 0):

The following code uses member/3, which has also to become
known as nth1/3. See here:

```
 http://storage.developerzen.com/fourrow.pro.txt
```

The predicate is nowadays found in library(lists) and has
possibly native support or a fast implementation:

```
 http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=nth1/3
```

But I guess asserting some facts and relying on argument
indexing might get you an even better result. See for
example here:

```
 http://www.mxro.de/applications/four-in-a-row
```

Hope this helps.

Bye

Comment: First link is outdated check https://developerzen.com/four-in-a-row-game-prolog/